# Action of $M_{\mu \nu}$ on local operators $\mathcal{O}(x)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conformal-field-theory, commutator

I'm following the [TASI Lectures on the Conformal Bootstrap](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982) by David Simmons-Duffin.

Let $M_{\mu \nu}$ be the conserved charge operator associated with rotations. The action of said operator on local operators follows a set of irreducible representations of the rotations groups $SO(d)$,

$$[M_{\mu \nu}, \mathcal{O}(0)^a] = (\mathcal{S}_{\mu \nu})_{b}^{\,a}\mathcal{O}(0)^b\tag{39}$$

where $a$ and $b$ are indices for the $SO(d)$ rep. of $\mathcal{O}$. To study the action of $M_{\mu \nu}$ on local operators far from the origin, one does (using Euclidean signature and ignoring spin indices)

\begin{split}
[M_{\mu \nu}, \mathcal{O}(x)] & = [M_{\mu \nu}, e^{x\cdot P}\mathcal{O}(0)e^{-x\cdot P}]  \\
 & = e^{x\cdot P}
[M_{\mu \nu}, \mathcal{O}(0)e^{-x\cdot P}]+[M_{\mu \nu}, e^{x\cdot P}]\mathcal{O}(0)e^{-x\cdot P}\\
& = \mathcal{S}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{O}(x)+e^{x\cdot P}\mathcal{O}(0)
[M_{\mu \nu},e^{-x\cdot P}]+[M_{\mu \nu}, e^{x\cdot P}]\mathcal{O}(0)e^{-x\cdot P}\\
& = \mathcal{S}_{\mu \nu}\mathcal{O}(x)+\mathcal{O}(x)
e^{x\cdot P}M_{\mu \nu}e^{-x\cdot P}+
e^{x\cdot P}M_{\mu \nu}e^{-x\cdot P}\mathcal{O}(x)-\left[M_{\mu \nu},\mathcal{O}(x)\right].
\end{split}

I can now use the Hausdorff formula, but this gives me an infinite set of commutators that I cannot simplify, namely

$$\left[P \cdot x,M_{\mu \nu}\right]$$

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to determine this commutator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$[M_{\mu\nu}, P_{\eta}] = \delta_{\nu\eta} P_{\mu} - \delta_{\mu\eta} P_{\nu}$$ and $$e^X Y e^{-X} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \underbrace{[X,[X,\ldots,[X}_{\text{n times}},Y]\ldots] \equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} [(X)^n,Y].$$ So essentially your task boils down to computing the $n$-times computator of $P$ and $M$. But since $[P,M] \sim P$, computing $[(P)^n,M]$ shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Might be a stupid question, but what about the commutator $[x_{\alpha},M_{\mu \nu}]$?

Comment: @miniplanck $x$ is not an operator here, it's merely a (Euclidean) vector by which you translate your operator from the origin. You may use, e.g., $a$ or $r$ instead of $x$ to make the notation less confusing.

Comment: Ah! That makes much more sense. Thank you very much!